# Lifetime of Subject variable

Tags: javascript, rxjs

What is a lifetime of variable `result` below? 
Is it alive after we leave `addIcons`?

```
addIcons():Observable<boolean>{
  const result = new Subject<boolean>();

  this.Service.getIcons().subscribe(icons => {

    result.next(true);
    result.complete();
  },
  error => {
    result.next(false);
    result.complete();
  });   

  return result.asObservable();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All variables declared within a function are local variables and override any variables already declared elsewhere.

All local variables only exist while the function is executing – they are not properties of the object. Local variables are newly created each time the function is executed.

However, the subscription `getIcons()` will live until you unsubscribe.

Are you trying to `map` the result of `getIcons()` to a boolean? If so, you might want to simplify your code to something like this:

```
addIcons(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.Service.getIcons().pipe(
      map(() => true),
      catchError(( => of(false))
  );
}
```